# Specify multiple directories for recursive search

Tags: bash

I have a bash script which searches through all the sub-directories (at all levels) given a target directory:

```
#! /bin/bash

DIRECTORIES="/home/me/target_dir_1"

for curr in $DIRECTORIES
do
   ...
```

Now I want the script to search multiple target directories such as `target_dir_1, target_dir_2, target_dir_3`. How should I modify the script to do this?

Answer (score 3):

use find instead.

```
find /home/me/target_dir_1 -type d
```

You can put that in a for loop:

```
for d in target_dir_1 target_dir_2 
do
   find /home/me/"$d" -type d
done
```

If it is always `/home/me`, and you want to search all the directories under that, do the follwing:

```
find /home/me -type d
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. but I think the answer i'm looking for is simply how to specify multiple directories for the variable `DIRECTORIES`, and the rest of the script should handle the task fine. What is the correct syntax for doing that?

Answer (score 3):

```
#!/bin/bash

GIVEN_DIR=$1  ## Or you could just set the value here instead of using $1.

while read -r DIR; do
   echo "$DIR"  ## do something with subdirectory.
done < <(exec find "$GIVEN_DIR" -type d -mindepth 1)
```

Run with:

```
bash script.sh dir
```

Note that word splitting is a bad idea so don't do this:

```
IFS=$'\n'
for DIR in $(find "$GIVEN_DIR" -type d -mindepth 1); do
   echo "$DIR"  ## do something with subdirectory.
done
```

Neither with other forms like when you could use `-print0` for `find`, although it's fine if you still use `while`:

```
while read -r DIR -d $'\0'; do
   echo "$DIR"  ## do something with subdirectory.
done < <(exec find "$GIVEN_DIR" -type d -mindepth 1 -print0)
```

Lastly you could record those on an array:

```
readarray -t SUBDIRS < <(exec find "$GIVEN_DIR" -type d -mindepth 1)
for DIR in "${SUBDIRS[@]}"; do
   echo "$DIR"  ## do something with subdirectory.
done
```

Answer (score 2):

Say:

```
for i in /home/me/target_dir_{1..5}; do
  echo $i;
done
```

This would result in:

```
/home/me/target_dir_1
/home/me/target_dir_2
/home/me/target_dir_3
/home/me/target_dir_4
/home/me/target_dir_5
```

Alternatively, you can specify the variable as an array and loop over it:

```
DIRECTORIES=( /home/me/target_dir_1 /home/me/target_dir_2 /home/me/target_dir_3 )
for i in ${DIRECTORIES[@]}; do echo $i ; done
```

which would result in

```
/home/me/target_dir_1
/home/me/target_dir_2
/home/me/target_dir_3
```

Comment: so how do I initialize the variable `DIRECTORIES` to contain multiple directories (and they do not always follow the 'target_dir_*' pattern..

Comment: This won't apply to all levels.